# Input type date doesn't show correctly on tablet

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I use angularJS to display an array of object and I have to display a date. This date is stock in String like "2014-06-02" and in the ng-repeat I have :

```
<input type="date" value="{{myObject.date}}">
```

It work perfectly on desktop like Chrome or Opera but on tablet (iPad and Android Tablet) the field is black but when I click on it I can see the corect value in the calendar.
What is wrong with my code ?

**Edit :**

As you can see on this picture , I display my date on a p markup like that :

```
<p>date : {{metrage.dateFormat}}</p>
```

The first date input is my

```
<input type="date" value="{{myObject.date}}">
```

And the last date input is :

```
<input type="date" value="2014-06-02">
```

[image: my empty date input]

And here is when I click on the empty input : It shows my date

[image]

Comment: Can you show CSS? Can you show a screenshot?

Comment: I add some screen on my question. I use bootstrap as CSS and I my input have these class :"form-control input-lg"

Comment: So, myObject.date might not be a yyyy-mm-dd string, or Angular doesn't work.  I recommend to check DOM structure with remove inspector.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is wrong with your code.

According to http://caniuse.com/input-datetime IE, Safari, Opera Mini, Firefox for Android, IE Mobile. **Global support for the date type is currently only at 12.03%**

The webkit used by ipad, (safari), still does not support it, I'm not sure what browser android is using. Chrome for android is suppose to support it.

Comment: I tried <input type="date" value="2014-06-02"> and it work...but I can't find the difference between these two things...

Comment: Here is some more information on the issues as the browsers are working to support type date ... http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Nov/08/HTML5-Input-typedate-Formatting-Issues ... what make and version of browsers are you using. If this is for the public then the public need to use a browser that will display your content.

Comment: I don't think it's a compatibility problem because if I write the date in the code it work perfectly on iPad and on Android tablet, it's only on the ng-repeat, is that possible that it's because in the JSON it is store as a String ?

Comment: browser compatibility doesn't matter in this question though Mobile Safari and Firefox for Android support type=date.